# Trigger procedure for getting modified column names

Tags: postgresql

I've been looking for a way to get the names of any modified columns during an INSERT inside a trigger function. I can get the table modified using the trigger procedure TG_TABLE_NAME, is there anything similar for modified columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no equivalent to `TG_TABLE_NAME` for column names. You need to compare the `old` and `new` records in an `UPDATE` trigger.

For `INSERT` triggers the idea of "modified" column names doesn't even make any sense. Do you mean columns that are not at their default values?

Anyway, you need to examine the `NEW` and (where it applies) `OLD` records. This can be tricky to do dynamically. The `hstore` extension is often the most useful tool, as it allows you to do comparisons between and iterations over columns of unknown rowsets.

Comment: My bad, I was talking about the UPDATE trigger itself. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @Shalin Makes more sense. You might find this informative: wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Audit_trigger_91plus